# How do I assign monospaced font to emails from certain senders in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

A wiki system sends me update notifications. I have no influence how the sender formats these messages. I read these emails with the Office 365 desktop installed version of Outlook. (`Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus Version 1708 (Build 8431.2236 Click-to-Run)`)

## Ugly current display

Now this is supposed to be a plain text table, however it looks really ugly when rendered using a proportional font like so:

[image]

## Nice desired display

If in fact it where rendered using a monospaced (a.k.a. fixed-width/fixed-pitch/non-proportional) font then it should look much prettier like so:

```
>             Project: FooProject
>          Issue Type: FooIssue
>          Components: FooComponent, BarComponent
>            Reporter: FooReporter
>            Assignee: FooAssignee
>              Labels: FooLabel, BarLabel
```

Everything is now nicely aligned by the colons.

## Question

QUESTION: Is there a way for me to force mails from that sender to ALWAYS render in a monospaced font?

Comment: which version of outlook do you use? is it the desktop version or online? How do you change the font manually?

Comment: @MátéJuhász: 1.: `Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus Version 1708 (Build 8431.2236 Click-to-Run)`, 2.: Deskop, 3.: Not at all. I just pasted into Notepad++ and noticed that things look a lot nicer when in a fixed width font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can control it at message level, there is just one general option for it.

[How to show fixed width font for plain text e-mails only?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_windows8-mso_2010/how-to-show-fixed-width-font-for-plain-text-e/6015c0da-2cf3-4e2c-997b-5fa8b1796fb9):

> File > Options > Mail > Stationery and Fonts > Set the font for plain text e-mails to a monospaced font (say) Courier New.

Comment: Hrm. I feared there wouldn't be such an option. -- Although message level wouldn't be necessary. Sender/contact level would be enough. I know you can select `Send Plain Text only` at contact level. I'd just like the reverse. Something like `Always format incoming mail from this contact as plain text`.

Comment: No, there is nothing like that. The issue is that you can't edit incoming messages, changing font would be that. The only option you have is to change which font to use for messages where font information is not included (= plain text).